# Should I use ExecutorService in a spring Component?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, executorservice

I've a spring component which looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ProfileService {

  private final ExecutorService executorService = ExecutorFactory.newThreadPoolExecutor(getClass().getSimpleName(),
  5, 100, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
  new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1), new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());

  public Map<Integer, String> getProfiles(String client, Set<String> pIds) {
    Map<String, Future<Optional<Profile>>> profileFutures = new HashMap<>(pIds.size());
    for (String pId : pIds) {
      locationsFutures.put(clusterMcId, executorService.submit(() -> getProfile(client, pId)));
    }
    Map<String, String> profileNames = new HashMap<>();
    for (String pId : profileFutures.keySet()) {
        profileFutures.get(pId).get(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).ifPresent(
          profile -> profileNames.put(pId, profile.getName());
    }
    return profileNames;
  }
```

I just make parallel calls to get profiles using their ids and wait for futures to complete. I keep getting `RejectedExecutionException` while submitting a task to `executorService`. Now my questions are as follows:

1. Is it a good idea to use `ExecutorService` in spring components? Since the same component will be used across parallel tomcat requests and each of those requests submits 5 tasks to the thread pool, won't it have 5x concurrent requests tasks?
2. Is there a better way to do my work? I can increase blocking queue size but how long is gonna that hold.  (Batching is not an option).

Comment: Any reason to use new ```ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1), new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy()```? If I understand correctly, you create a thread pool with pool size 1 for only 1 task and your ```ExecutorService``` throws ```RejectedExecutionException``` exception when you try to submit the second task.

```ExecutorFactory``` what library do you use? Why not create a thread pool via ```Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())```?

Generallly it's okay to use ```ExecutorService``` in spring components.

Comment: If I understand correctly, tasks will only go to `ArrayBlockingQueue` if all of my threads are busy. I have a cap of 100 threads, that means I should only get `RejectedExecutionException` once I've 102 concurrent submissions.